# Ubuntu 16 doesnt let me connect to the internet after fresh install

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, internet

I just installed Ubuntu 16 because i need it for work.
So after deleting Ubuntu 20 and installing Ubuntu 16 i was shocked bc i cant do anything with the internet

[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTmtV.jpg)

Comment: Maybe your computer is too new for Ubuntu 16 (I guess you mean 16.04.x LTS). Please tell us about the computer: brand name and model, and of the wifi chip/card: brand name and model. Or is there even problems with wired internet alias Ethernet? In that case tell us about the ethernet chip/card.

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 16 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.  (Canonical & Ubuntu have used *yy* releases for specialist releases since 2016; you appear to show a desktop releases but no *yy* releases have a desktop by default; desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format)

Comment: @sudodos I have a predator helios 300 from Acer. I got internet now via LAN cable

Answer (score 1):

can you please explain why you need to install an obsolete/old version rather than currently supported. Generally the version is a minimum not an absolute. If you had a working Ubuntu 20.04 I woulld be tempted to return to that.
What do you need to run that works in  16.* that doesn't in 20.04?

More detail is required by what you mean by "cant do anything" with the internet.

Can you ping?
Are you set up to use DHCP?

(can't yet comment so sorry for "answer")

Comment: I need to use Ubuntu 16 bc i am working with ROS and the robot i want to simulate just works on the ROS version that runs on 16.